# Sending html in a email method with meteor

Tags: javascript, html, email, meteor

I want to send a email with meteor, that has html table that later I will style.

I have the following code, the email sends fine however, the html is received as a plain text string not as html itself. I am sure there is a simple fix, thanks for help in advanced.

**client**
`/client/contactSend.js`

```
Template.contact.events({
  'submit #generalContactForm': function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    fname = $(".fname").val();

    $(".hideFormGeneral").css("display","none");
    $(".loader").css("display","block");

    var data = {
      name: "test"
    };

    var htmlEmail = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.contact_email,data);
    Meteor.call('sendEmail','dev@anderskitson.ca','bob@example.com','Hello from Meteor!',htmlEmail);

  }

});
```

`/client/contact_email.html

```
<html>

<table width="100%" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="postfooter">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
              <tbody>
                 <!-- Spacing -->
                 <tr>
                    <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                 </tr>
                 <!-- Spacing -->
                 <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;color: #282828" st-content="preheader">
                       red <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #eacb3c">Unsubscribe here </a>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <!-- Spacing -->
                 <tr>
                    <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                 </tr>
                 <!-- Spacing -->
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of postfooter -->

</html>
```

**server**
`/server/sendMail.js`

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
    check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

    // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
    // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
    this.unblock();

    Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      text: text
    });
  }
});

Meteor.startup(function () {
  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://dev@anderskitson.ca:F0EC-random@smtp.mandrillapp.com:587';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling [Email.send](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email_send) with an `html` parameter instead of a `text` parameter:

```
Email.send({
  to: to,
  from: from,
  subject: subject,
  html: text
});
```

You may want to rename the `text` variable to make this more clear and/or consider having one method for plaintext emails and another for HTML-based emails.